# Error al enviar la consulta de inserción de datos PHP,MYSQL con metodo POST

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

Hace poco me he adentrado en lo que es PHP con base de datos en MySQL, estoy creando una página en la cual pueda enviar datos desde la página hacia la base de datos pero por más que haga me sigue generando error, tal vez ustedes me puedan ayudar a encontrar el error, de antemano muchas gracias, adjunto mi código de conexión a la base de datos.

```html
<?php 

        $conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","tienda");

    if(!$conexion){
        echo "Conexión fallida";
    }
?>
```

Así mismo mi código de formulario PHP

```html
<form action="proceso_guardar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset class="contenedor">
        <legend>Agregar nuevo producto</legend>
        <label for="descripcion">Descripción</label>
        <input type="text" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripción del producto" required>

        <label for="precio">Precio</label>
        <input type="number" min="0.00" max="10000.00" step="00.1" name="precio" placeholder="Precio del producto" required>

        <label for="categoria">Categoría</label>
            <select name="categoria">
                <option value="0">Seleccione una opción</option> 
                <option value="alimentos">Alimentos</option> 
                <option value="cabello">Cabello</option> 
                <option value="jabones">Jabones</option>
                <option value="cuidadoper">Cuidado personal</option> 
                <option value="cuidadoint">Cuidado íntimo</option> 
            </select>

        <label for="imagen">Imagen</label>
        <input type="file" name="imagen" required/> 
    </fieldset>
    <div class="contenedor" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="boton boton-verde">
    </div>
</form>
```

y por último mi código del proceso de PHP para envío de datos

```html
<?php 

    include("conexion.php");

    $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
    $precio = $_POST["precio"];
    $categoria = $_POST["categoria"];
    $imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"]));

    $query = "INSERT INTO productos VALUES ('',$descripcion','$precio','$categoria','$imagen')";

    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

    if($resultado){
        echo "Insertado correctamente";
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }

?>
```

espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que imprime, solamente la palabra `Error`? Para depurar captura el mensaje de error en la base de datos para saber exactamente a qué se debe el error, poniendo esto: **`echo "Error: {$conexion->error}";`** Luego que sepamos el error puedes quitar `$conexion->error` y poner un mensaje personalizado, pues no conviene mostrar al usuario mensajes de error internos del programa.

Comment: Hice lo que me sugeriste pero la cadena me aparece en blanco, solo devuelve la palabra "error:"

Comment: Entonces la conexión no es válida o el include no se está haciendo bien. ¿`conexion.php` y el archivo donde la usas (`proceso_guardar.php`) están en la misma carpeta?

Comment: Si, ambos están en la misma carpeta, también me puse a pensar en un posible problema de conexión así que encerré el código en un if `if($conexion){aquí el resto del código incluida la consulta}` pero a pesar de eso no me funciona.

Comment: Ya, de todos modos tienes esto: `echo "Conexión fallida";` que debería imprimirse en caso de que no conectase. Es incompatible que no salga ese mensaje y que no muestre el error, por lo que pensé que la conexión no se estaba incluyendo bien. Puedes revisar el log de errores, que se crea en la carpeta donde ejecutas el archivo `proceso_guardar.php` allí te dirá qué error está ocurriendo exactamente. Revísalo y coméntanos qué error es.

Comment: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\MAMP\htdocs\tienda\php\conexion.php on line 8
mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\MAMP\htdocs\tienda\php\proceso_guardar.php on line 12
main(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\MAMP\htdocs\tienda\php\proceso_guardar.php on line 17

Esos son los errores que tiene el log

Comment: Te está denegando el acceso a la base de datos, parece que el usuario `root` tiene una clave y debes poner cual es en vez de dejar en blanco el parámetro para la clave: `$conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","PONER-LA-CLAVE-AQUI","tienda");`

Comment: Ya está solucionado eso, error mio ya que el la página principal del localhost aparece la contraseña, ahora me salta el siguiente error **Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Chill 150ml','72','cuidadoper','????\0JFIF\0\0\0d\0d\0\0??\0C\0' at line 1** ya he probado cambiando `$resultado= query($conexion->$query)` por `$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$query)` pero me salta siempre el mismo error

Comment: Eso probablemente es debido a la imagen. ¿Tú quieres guardar una imagen en sí en la BD? ¿La columna donde iría `$imagen` es del tipo `BLOB`? No haces nada con cambiar `query` por `mysqli_query`, son dos estilos distintos, pero hacen lo mismo y el estilo que usas (orientado a objetos) es más claro y más corto, no lo cambies por el estilo procedural `mysqli_` que es más antiguo y más verboso.

Comment: Si, lo que quiero es enviar una imagen a la base de datos, el campo es tipo LONGBLOB

Comment: Ya está solucionado, cuando cambié el código, por error borré una comilla en la consulta, muchas gracias por tu ayuda @A.Cedano

Comment: De todos modos, para insertar datos BLOB deberías escribir una consulta preparada y usar [`send_long_data`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php), si no, tu script se puede bloquear en cualquier momento si manejas archivos más grandes o si hay conexiones concurrentes tratando de subir varios archivos pesados al mismo tiempo.